# Redirect URL for Spring OAuth2 app on Azure with Active Directory: Invalid Redirect URI Parameter

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I am following the following two tutorials of the Azure documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin
which shows how to deploy a simple Spring Boot application to Azure and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory
to set up and use an active directory as OAuth2 server with a Spring Security OAuth2 Client.
Basically I just add the OAuth2 dependencies to Maven, a WebSecurityConfig class as shown in the second document and additionally also the azure.activedirectoy and spring.security properties.

When the application is just run from my local computer the login and redirection works fine. But when the application is deployed to Azure, I get an application error saying: Invalid Redirect URI Parameter. I think I have set the redirect-uri correctly as

```
https://{baseHost}{basePort}{basePath}/login/oauth2/code/azure
```

in the application properties as well as in the application registration with my Active Directory.

As far as I can see the authorization request uses the right parameters:

```
response_type: code
client_id: 4b5fbcfd-c35f-4bab-bc45-374c7e1dead8
scope: openid https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
state: yMvo62R-6vgjETSGr_mnh4iIMZimVnFYZRyiGFaOPtE=
redirect_uri: https://myappname.azurewebsites.net/login/oauth2/code/azure
nonce: FUXJ5GoJ2NuNVx2ORU70YCqnJkEj8FRYHEJYMutEQzo
```

So, what could the Invalid Redirect URI Parameter be, and how can I change this?

Comment: Just to ensure, you have already added your actual Azure web app url https://myappname.azurewebsites.net/login/oauth2/code/azure as the reply url in your Azure ad app?

Comment: yes, as redirect-uri: 'https://{baseHost}{basePort}{basePath}/login/oauth2/code/azure' in the application.yaml, and also in the app registration in the Active Directory:  "replyUrlsWithType": [
  {
   "url": "https://myappname.azurewebsites.net/login/oauth2/code/azure",
   "type": "Web"
  }
 ]

Comment: In addition I had an error with the id-token which is described here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/288. The solution was, as described in this issue, to set oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed these two tutorials, it works fine on local environment, on Azure webapp, I encountered redirect url mismatch error.

The cause is that the redirect_uri is always started with http. After adding `server.forward-headers-strategy=native` in applications.properties, it works. (I am using spring boot 2.2)

Here is the pom.xml for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <parent> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>  
    <relativePath/>  
    <!-- lookup parent from repository --> 
  </parent>  
  <groupId>com.example.ad</groupId>  
  <artifactId>ad</artifactId>  
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
  <name>ad</name>  
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>  
  <properties> 
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>  
    <azure.version>2.2.0</azure.version> 
  </properties>  
  <dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  
      <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
      <scope>test</scope>  
      <exclusions> 
        <exclusion> 
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>  
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>  
      <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId> 
    </dependency> 
  </dependencies>  
  <dependencyManagement> 
    <dependencies> 
      <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  
        <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>  
        <version>${azure.version}</version>  
        <type>pom</type>  
        <scope>import</scope> 
      </dependency> 
    </dependencies> 
  </dependencyManagement>  
  <build> 
    <plugins> 
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
      </plugin>  
      <plugin> 
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  
        <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>1.9.0</version>  
        <configuration>
          <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
          <resourceGroup>ad-1582615028467-rg</resourceGroup>
          <appName>ad-1582615028467</appName>
          <pricingTier>P1v2</pricingTier>
          <region>westeurope</region>
          <runtime>
            <os>linux</os>
            <javaVersion>jre8</javaVersion>
            <webContainer>jre8</webContainer>
          </runtime>
            <appSettings>
                <property>
                    <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
                    <value>-Dserver.port=80</value>
                </property>
            </appSettings>
          <deployment>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                <includes>
                  <include>*.jar</include>
                </includes>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </deployment>
        </configuration>
      </plugin> 
    </plugins> 
  </build> 
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, right, after adding server.forward-headers-strategy=native in applications.properties, it works. (plus the oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow to true)

Comment: This didn't work for me... Can you please expand a little on how this setting actually works? I think it has something to do with the web apps reverse proxy and Spring boot's Tomcat servlet container, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @GerardV, Did you get a solution as Im facing similar issue and erver.forward-headers-strategy=native does not work for me

Comment: Ah, yes @shaguftasyed, I posted what worked for me below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67634165/796206

Comment: Yes, FRAMEWORK did work for me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What eventually worked for me, was the following application.yml.

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: FRAMEWORK
  port: 8080
  error:
    include-message: "always" ## You want to be able to supply meaningful error resolution hints to end users.
  servlet:
    context-path: /myappcontextpath
```